# jest.requireActual is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

Trying to mock `jwt_decode` I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: jest.requireActual is not a function

I'm not sure if I have to include any @types or some dependency, or even it might be something with the way I'm mocking the function.

my.spec.js:

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

jest.mock("jwt-decode", () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual("jwt-decode");
  return {
    ...original,
    jwt_decode: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      expInMilli: 12345
    }))
  };
}); // ....
```

I'm using jest with RCA, in case it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

`requireActual` aside, you appear to be going a long way for a shortcut

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'

jest.mock('jwt-decode');

jwt_decode.mockReturnValue({
  expInMilli: 12345
});
```

Comment: I actually gave up, as I couldn't spend more time on that and came up with something close to what you did `jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => jest.fn().mockreturnValue...)`. But I didn't know you can mock the functions like this. Thanks.